# Is there a standard F# function for separating a sequence of Choices?

Tags: f#

I'm looking for a standard F# function that takes a sequence of 2-choices and returns a pair of sequences:

```
let separate (choices : seq<Choice<'T1, 'T2>>) : seq<'T1> * seq<'T2> = ...
```

A naive implementation is pretty simple:

```
let separate choices =
    let ones =
        choices
            |> Seq.choose (function
                | Choice1Of2 one -> Some one
                | _ -> None)
    let twos =
        choices
            |> Seq.choose (function
                | Choice2Of2 two -> Some two
                | _ -> None)
    ones, twos
```

This works fine, but iterates the sequence twice, which is less than ideal. Is this function defined in one of the semi-standard libraries? I looked around, but couldn't find it. (If it exists, I'm sure it goes by some other name.)

For bonus points, versions that work with 3-choices, 4-choices, and so on, would also be nice, as would versions for `List`, `Array`, etc. Thanks.

Comment: In Haskell it's `partitionEithers` or `unzipEithers` ([hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BEither%20a%20b%5D%20-%3E%20(%5Ba%5D%2C%20%5Bb%5D))), but I can't find anything with such signature in FSharpx or FSharpPlus

Comment: It's `partitionMap id` in F#+ http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus//extensions.html#Partitioning

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. It looks like `partitionMap id` will match what I asked for, (although it doesn't support sequences). Thank you for finding it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find builtin implementation but can write my own.
It uses `IEnumerator<>` based approach, so it will work with any collection type but it's not optimal (e.g. arrays will work slower than could be). Order is reversed (easy to fix with `ResizeArray` but more code). Also this version is not lazy, but can be easily adapted to work with `Choice<'a, 'b, 'c>` and others

```ml
let splitChoices2 (choices: Choice<'a, 'b> seq) =
    let rec inner (it: IEnumerator<_>) acc1 acc2 =
        if it.MoveNext() then
            match it.Current with
            | Choice1Of2 c1 -> inner it (c1 :: acc1) acc2
            | Choice2Of2 c2 -> inner it acc1 (c2 :: acc2)
        else
            acc1, acc2

    inner (choices.GetEnumerator()) [] []

let choices = [
        Choice1Of2 11
        Choice2Of2 "12"
        Choice1Of2 21
        Choice2Of2 "22"
    ]
choices |> splitChoices2 |> printfn "%A"
```

Update: `ResizeArray` based approach without reversed order and potentially less expensive enumeration

```ml
let splitChoices2 (choices: Choice<'a, 'b> seq) =
    let acc1 = ResizeArray()
    let acc2 = ResizeArray()
    
    for el in choices do
        match el with
        | Choice1Of2 c1 -> acc1.Add c1
        | Choice2Of2 c2 -> acc2.Add c2

    acc1, acc2
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the second version but will keep this open for a while to see if anyone else has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of inspired by TraverseA but has come out quite different. Here is a single pass solution (UPDATE: however while the core algorithm might be single pass from List to List, but getting it to match your type signature, and ordering the result the same way makes it 3*O(n), it depends how important the ordering and type signature are to you)

```
let choices = seq {Choice1Of2(1) ; Choice2Of2(2) ; Choice2Of2(3) ; Choice1Of2(4)}
let seperate' choices  = 
    let rec traverse2ChoicesA tupleSeq choices = 
        match choices with
        | [] -> fst tupleSeq |> List.rev |>Seq.ofList , snd tupleSeq |> List.rev |> Seq.ofList  
        | (Choice1Of2 f)::tl -> traverse2ChoicesA (f::fst tupleSeq, snd tupleSeq) tl
        | (Choice2Of2 s)::tl -> traverse2ChoicesA (fst tupleSeq, s::snd tupleSeq) tl
    traverse2ChoicesA ([],[]) <| List.ofSeq choices
 
seperate' choices;;

val seperate' : choices:seq<Choice<'a,'b>> -> seq<'a> * seq<'b>
val it : seq<int> * seq<int> = ([1; 4], [2; 3])
```

Update: To be clear, if ordering and List instead of Seq are ok then this is a single pass:

```
let choices = [Choice1Of2(1) ; Choice2Of2(2) ; Choice2Of2(3) ; Choice1Of2(4)]

let seperate' choices  = 
    let rec traverse2ChoicesA (tupleSeq) choices = 
        match choices with
        | [] -> tupleSeq
        | (Choice1Of2 f)::tl -> traverse2ChoicesA (f :: fst tupleSeq, snd tupleSeq) tl
        | (Choice2Of2 s)::tl -> traverse2ChoicesA (fst tupleSeq, s:: snd tupleSeq) tl
    traverse2ChoicesA ([],[]) choices

seperate' choices;;

val choices : Choice<int,int> list =
  [Choice1Of2 1; Choice2Of2 2; Choice2Of2 3; Choice1Of2 4]
val seperate' : choices:Choice<'a,'b> list -> 'a list * 'b list
val it : int list * int list = ([4; 1], [3; 2])
```

You might find something more general, performant and with appropriate type signature in the FSharpPlus "semi-standard" library using TraverseA?

Comment: Actually it's not single pass solution. Time complexity is O(3*n), even if scientifically it's still O(n). One pass to convert seq to list, one pass iterate resulting list and 2 passes on half of collection to reverse order.

Comment: I did that to match the signature of the OP. However maybe the list to Seq conversions and reverses are not required. That is what I meant to say, I will update this answer, thanks